# MyMaps. Failed to import file from Google Drive, check network connection and try again

Tags: google-sheets, mymaps

Im trying to import a file to [MyMaps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/?hl=en) via Google Drive.

It has been working previously but now it does not. Tt gives the following error:

`Failed to import file from Google Drive, check network connection and try again`

[image]

I even tried to a use a very simple Google Sheets file that has just 2 rows and 3 columns. If I export to CSV and them import that from my computer it works well.

Does anyone have insight on this issue? There is not much hope trying to get support from Google.